# IE7 - how do you make a message bubble work?

Tags: css, css-position, internet-explorer-7

I am trying to make a message bubble, and I've got it working on all browsers with exception to IE7. The bubble needs to wrap itself around variable width content, so it's width will depend on the amount of content. It may grow to 100%, but it may only be 100px wide if the message is short. This is where I'm running into problems with IE.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w9Vdh/

The main construct of the bubble is a top row, middle row and bottom row. I've got a sprite and a couple other background images that I use render the graphics. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="thread-item-wrapper">
    <div class="thread-item-horiz thread-item-top">
        <div class="thread-item-corner thread-item-topleft"></div>
        <div class="thread-item-corner thread-item-topright"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="thread-item-middle">
        <div class="thread-item-content-wrapper">
            <div class="thread-item-label">You:</div>
            <div class="thread-item-content">
                <div class="thread-item-msg">
                    <div class="thread-item-content-top"></div>
                    <p>Message</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="thread-item-horiz thread-item-bottom">
        <div class="thread-item-corner thread-item-bottomleft"></div>
        <div class="thread-item-corner thread-item-bottomright"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="thread-item-date">Aug 18, 2011 12:01 PM</div>
</div>
```

Here's what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

And here's what it looks like in IE7:

[image]

Comment: Remove all those divs and classes, switch to `border-radius`, `linear-gradient` and `:before` for the little arrow and forget IE? :P

Comment: I know, right!!!! I'll do that in about 3 years... when IE 7 and 8 are DEAD!

Comment: Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w9Vdh/4/ I was able to get the top/bottom to be the right height. I can't get them to span the width of the wrapper.

Comment: Dear Redtopia please see my answer and let me know this is what you are expected or some thing else or i am lagging some where, please let me know so i can change the code as per your need.

Comment: Sorry... I had meetings this afternoon!

Comment: Dear see my updated fiddle for sent bubble fix for IE7. Let me know if you face any other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the fiddle for code and demo-

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w9Vdh/6

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w9Vdh/6/embedded/result/

screen shot of IE7:

[image]

**Updated fiddle for sent bubble fix for IE7**

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8NpwH/2/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8NpwH/2/embedded/result/

[image]

Changes in code html:

```
<div class="thread-item-clear">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="thread-item-date"><div style="text-align:right;">Mar 23, 2012 12:41 PM</div></div>
```

Css:

```
.thread-item-sent .thread-item-date {/*clear:left; float:right;*/ margin:0px 4px 0 15px; } /* <--- this line --- */
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain what you changed? I'm reading through the code and it's not obvious. Great work Dinesh!

Comment: I was able to figure out exactly what you changed, but it took some time. Thank you very much for your help. If you document your answer, that will be even more helpful. After adding your fix, I found that it only works on received messages. Here's a fiddle with both a sent and received message: http://jsfiddle.net/8NpwH/  The sent message fills the width, and it has something to do with the date. If I get rid of this CSS: .thread-item-sent .thread-item-date {clear:left; float:right; margin:20px 15px 0 0;}, the bubble fits the width of the content, but the date is missing.

Comment: Dinesh, thanks for your help! Any ideas on getting the sent message bubble to work correctly?

Comment: dear what is the problem with sent bubble? can you specify or show me screen shot.

Comment: See above comment. The fiddle is here: jsfiddle.net/8NpwH. The sent message (on the right) doesn't fit the content width... it fills the width of the container, and it has something to do with the date. Thank you Dinesh!

Comment: Dear i read your comment and saw your fiddle to but i m not getting what exactly you want. But i have one query why the bubble have blue images? i mean blue and silver color both images? Please specify clearly so i can help you. I m waiting.

Comment: In production, the "sent bubble" is all blue, but to be quick, I only changed the images that needed to be changed so you could see the bubble in the other direction. I'll attach a screenshot.

Comment: do you want the right bubble in left or some thing else still you are not mentioning clearly what i have to change or show you output. Please please elaborate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9421/discussion-between-redtopia-and-dinesh-swami)

Answer (score 0):

"Received messages" work... the bubble wraps to the message width nicely. However, sent messages are being displayed full-width, and not sizing correctly to the message width. This has something to do with the date. In my fiddle ([jsfiddle.net/8NpwH](http://jsfiddle.net/8NpwH)) you'll see a comment in the CSS on the .thread-item-sent .thread-item-date style, which indicates the CSS that appears to be the problem. If you get rid of that CSS, the bubble sizes correctly, but the date is missing.

[image: screenshot]